# setRetainInstance in DialogFragment crash

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` attached to the activity, and when the screen rotates, the activity is destroyed, so does the `DialogFragment`, I want to retain the `DialogFragment` and my `DialogFragment` codes are as below, I add `setRetainInstance(true);` it will crash

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(sClassTag, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
    setStyle(style, theme);

}
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(sClassTag, "onCreateView");
    if(mView==null){
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_password,container,false);
    }
    addButtonListener();
    addEdittextListener();
    return mView;
}
```

I get the crash log here

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication/com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you post the code in which you call the DialogFragment from your Activity?

Comment: Sounds like you fell down one many Fragment pitfalls. I had the same problem as you and I was able to fix whilst reading through this excellent article: http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/ .

Answer (score 1):

Is your activity extends `FragmentActivity` & have you set `configChanges` in Manifest file for activity?

Take parent activity as `FragmentActivity` & inflate fragment as

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new Diafragment();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: My activity extends AppCompatActivity, in fact I create a middle fragment in activity and in the middle fragment I create dialogFragment object, so should I change Manifest for middle fragment or acitivity?

Comment: change parent acitivity of fragment in menifest

Comment: Can you give a sample of how to modify manifest and I use newInstace to create a DialogFragment object and call the show function, but when it rotates it will not enter the middle Fragment create part. So I want to maintain the dialogFragment instance

Comment: change in menifest:
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"     
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            >
Can you post whole code for activity & middle fragment?

Comment: I add it into activity mainfest but it does not work, and the whole code is too much, the overall logic is I create a middle fragment object in activity and call its function A, in function A I create dialog fragment object and call its show function B, and in function B I call show(FragmentManager,"dialog")

Answer (score 0):

I find another way is add a static value member and record the value you want to save in the newinstance to the static value member and then in onCreate function do the assign

Comment: This is not a very good way, if anyone have better solution please share it, thank you!